# Android Notification class not found

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm migrating from `GCM` to `FCM`, then I stuck in some steps here:
Current GCM library added by follow:

```
compile ("com.google.gcm:gcm-server:1.0.0")
```

After that, `gcm-server-1.0.0.jar` will be generated.
Now, for FCM, I add following dependency (as instruct in official fcm page) :
In `build.gradle`

```
dependencies { 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and in main `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

After build gradle, libraries have been generated like: `firebase-messenging-15.0.0.aar`

So, when create new `Notification`, I can't find class in library.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: refer this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Comment: Thanks, but it can't help. The problem is that I don't know how to do with aar file :).